A way of showing items from Pinia store
I am developing an recipe management app with Vue 3, Vuetify. I am using vue router and Pinia as a store. The app consists of two parts - search where user can search for a recipe trough an API and favorites section. Each user can add a recipe to favorites. Each part has it's own view and route.
I have a problem regarding showing items from the store.
In HomeView.vue I am subscribing to the state and saving the favorite recipes in local storage.
const store = useRecipesStore();

store.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
   localStorage.setItem('favoriteRecipes', JSON.stringify(state.favoriteRecipes));
});

In FavoritesView.vue I am trying to show them as in:
<template>
    <Recipes :recipes="recipes" />
</template>

<script setup>
    import { onMounted } from 'vue';
    import { useRecipesStore } from '@/stores/recipesStore.js';

    const store = useRecipesStore();

    const recipes = store.getFavoriteRecipes;

    onMounted(() => {
        const savedRecipes = localStorage.getItem('favoriteRecipes') 
            ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteRecipes')) 
            : [];

        store.setFavoriteRecipes(savedRecipes);
    });
</script>

I have tested that items do save to local storage and also fills in store.
The store:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useRecipesStore = defineStore('recipesStore', {
    state: () => ({
        recipes: [],
        favoriteRecipes: [],
        activeRecipe: null,
    }),
    getters: {
        getRecipes() {
            return this.recipes;
        },
        getFavoriteRecipes() {
            return this.favoriteRecipes;
        },
        canBeAddedToFavorites() {
            if (!this.activeRecipe) return false;

            return !this.favoriteRecipes.some(recipe => recipe.id === this.activeRecipe.id);
        },
    },
    actions: {
        addFavoriteRecipe(recipe) {
            this.$patch({
                favoriteRecipes: [...this.favoriteRecipes, recipe]
            });
        },
        setActiveRecipe(recipe) {
            this.$patch({
                activeRecipe: recipe
            });
        },
        setFavoriteRecipes(recipes) {
            this.$patch({
                favoriteRecipes: recipes
            });
        },
    },
});

The weirdest part is that on initial favorites page load the items do not show but when I visit home page and switch back they do show.
What could be the problem?

You disable reactivity by accessing store.getFavoriteRecipes in setup. Either use it consistently through the component or convert it to a computed, e.g with storeToRefs. It makes sense to move localStorage.getItem to the store. There are already persistence plugins for vue that prevent you from reinventing the wheel

Thanks, converting it to computed with storeToRefs worked. I am just starting to learn Pinia, there's lots I don't know yet. About persistence plugins - maybe you can recommend some?

pinia-plugin-persistedstate, it does what you're trying but in a more coherent way
